# How to play a video only when a key is held in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have code for pressing a key but I need to implement where the key is held to play the video

```
var vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');   
document.onkeypress = function(e){
    if((e || window.event).keyCode === 112){
        vid.paused ? vid.play() : vid.pause();
```

I’m aware I have to use onkeydown and onkeyup but not sure how

Comment: have a look at keydown and keyup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const vid = document.getElementById('myVideo');

const playPauseVideo = ev => {
  if (ev.key !== 'F1') return; // Do nothing if not F1
  ev.preventDefault();         // Prevent browser default action (on F1)
  vid[ev.type === 'keydown' ? 'play' : 'pause']();
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', playPauseVideo);
document.addEventListener('keyup', playPauseVideo);
```

```html
Press and hold F1 to play video
<video id="myVideo" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"></video>
```